# Nine-Patch Image Slicing, Padding Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

So I've patched an image however it has padding on the left and right which I DO NOT want, however when I patch the image without padding the corners on the image get distorted when it's drawn in a layout.

Below is a screenshot of how I am doing it, how would you overcome this issue?

[image]

Comment: There should be no padding if you don't put those black pixels on the right and bottom side. "There's padding" means that the text doesn't get to sides of the box? Maybe just specify padding with right and bottom pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just try to specify the padding the way it's meant to be specified, i.e. by drawing the bottom (and right if you want) border in 9-patch tool. Like this:[image]

This way the padding should be right (side to side) and corners not distorted.

Answer (score 0):

The left and top lines define the stretchable area. When you include your corners in the stretchable area, the image gets distorted. In this case, one black pixel touching the center of the image on the left and the same on the top would suffice.
To identify the rectangle for the view contents, and thus the padding, you can use right and bottom lines.